# How to apply expand() function to a list of file name in Vim script

Tags: vim

I know expand() function has many filename-modifiers
I have read :h filename-modifiers

```
% - current file name
%:p - full path
%:p:t - file name only
%:p:r - file name is removed
```

etc

Does anyone know how to apply expand() to a list of file names in Vim script? or is there any similar Vim function like expand()?

It seems to me expand() only applies on current file %. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Given a filename `foo`, (not current file) how can you "expand" to full path?  I have `/etc/foo; $HOME/foo; /tmp/foo and /foo/bar/foo/bar/foo` What do you really want ,pls make an example.

Comment: I mean if I have a list of files e.g  ['/hom/cat/f.txt', '/etc/vim.txt']  and I want to get the file extension/file path. Since expand() applies only on current file which is %.  In expand("%:p:h") returns path,  expand("%:p:t") returns file name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over your file names and apply the expand() function to it. Or use the map function like this `:let new_list=map(copy(list), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":p:t")')`
(Note this is untested. Quoting might need to be adjusted).

Comment: +1 for `fnamemodify` that actually does the job. -1 for suggestion with expand() which I don't see a way for it to work with variables/lists, etc. If that misleading (and possibly time consuming part) with expand() is deleted or - a syntax example with it shown then I can upvote.